# problems with 301 redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need to make some 301 redirects, like this:

```
/!go?ln=vector.dpsp&refs_=&m$id=27007&m$mid=27013    to  http://domain.com/catalog/paz-320412-vektor.htm
/!go?ln=1223-15-57-1223.html&m$id=27148&m$mid=27940  to   http://domain.com/catalog/gruzoviki/sedelnie-tyagachi-man
```

I tryed this code in .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ln=vector.dpsp&refs_=&m$id=27007&m$mid=27013
RedirectPermanent   /!go    http://domain.com/catalog/paz-320412-vektor.htm? 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ln=1223-15-57-1223.html&m$id=27148&m$mid=27940
RedirectPermanent   /!go    http://domain.com/catalog/gruzoviki/sedelnie-tyagachi-man?
```

But all this two urls are catched with first block and redirect goes always into `http://domain.com/catalog/paz-320412-vektor.htm`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of things wrong here. First, you need to escape the `$` symbols in your expression matching the **%{QUERY_STRING}**, it's a reserved symbol (for stuff like backreferences). The second thing is a `RewriteCond` doesn't affect a `RedirectPermanent`. Rewrite directives are part of mod_rewrite and Redirect directives are part of mod_alias, you can't tie a rewrite condition to a redirect, you need to use `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ln=vector.dpsp&refs_=&m\$id=27007&m\$mid=27013
RewriteRule ^\!go$ http://domain.com/catalog/paz-320412-vektor.htm? [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ln=1223-15-57-1223.html&m\$id=27148&m\$mid=27940
RewriteRule ^\!go$ http://domain.com/catalog/gruzoviki/sedelnie-tyagachi-man? [R=301,L]
```